# Codeigniter Pagination without URI Segments

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I'm building an image rating application, in which the main page is basically a grid of images with simple yes/no voting buttons at the bottom of each image.

I'm using Codeigniter for the server-side, Bootstrap (both CSS and JS) for the interface.

Now, I don't want to load all the images at once, but rather divide the images up to pages, wach page containing 10 images to reduce loading times.

I've been looking over the documentation @ [The CI Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) Which wants me to utilise a variation of this code:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'imgapp.com';
$config['total_rows'] = 100;
$config['per_page'] = 10; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Which Produces This:

[image]

The problem is, I haven't built it in a way that enables URI segments.

So, the links are quite useless - they are pointing to an adress of this sort:

`http://www.imgapp.com/default_controller/3`

Which is useless for me.

How do I configure the pagination to work with my image app?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html
The keys to configure pagination are:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it.

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
base_url This is the full URL to the controller class/function containing your pagination. In the example above, it is pointing to a controller called "Test" and a function called "page". Keep in mind that you can re-route your URI if you need a different structure.
```

Comment: Read The Question - I've Looked At It.